# Why JQGrid shows empty records in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I have a problem that JQGrid load the data but show empty records. This is my controller action method:

```
public ActionResult Database(string server,string database, string username, string password)
        {
            UserAthentication U = new UserAthentication();
            U.ServerName = server;
            U.DatabaseName = database;
            U.Username = username;
            U.Password = password;
            Database db = new Database();



            var Names = db.GetDatabaseNames(U); //This method returns the string list and i debugged it it returns the data correctly.

            var jsondata = new
            {
                total = 1,
                page = 1,
                records = 0,
                rows = Names
            };

            return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

This is JQgrid code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#b1').click(function () {
        var server = $("#ServerName").val();
        var database = $("#DatabaseName").val();
        var username = $("#Username").val();
        var password = $("#Password").val();
        var URL = '/Home/Database?server=' + server+"&database="+database+"&username="+username+"&password="+password;

        $("#Grid").jqGrid({
            url: URL,
            datatype: 'json',

            colNames: ['Tables Name'],
            colModel: [

                {  name: 'TABLE_NAME', index: 'TABLE_NAME' },


            ],
            jsonReader: {
                root: 'rows',
                page: 'page',
                total: 'total',
                records: 'records',

                repeatitems: false
            },
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            width: 600,
            viewrecords: true,
            emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: 'Databases',
            loadonce: false,

        });
    });

});
```

It shows the empty rows. There are 4 rows that should show and it shows 4 empty rows
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
colModel: [
    {  name: 'TABLE_NAME', index: 'TABLE_NAME' },
],
```

you do not use TABLE_NAME but instead you use columns name like this:

```java
colModel: [
    {  name: 'Column_NAME', index: 'Column_NAME' },
    {  name: 'Column_NAME', index: 'Column_NAME' },
    {  name: 'Column_NAME', index: 'Column_NAME' },
    {  name: 'Column_NAME', index: 'Column_NAME' },
],
```